# iSeries JAVA program with RPGLE Interface crashes when processing images

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg

I have made a java program that creates PDF files based to GnuPdf.  It runs perfectly when run using native java code (on windows or iSeries QSH), however, when run through an RPGLE interface, the program crashes (at what seems like random intervals) when processing images.  I tracked down one of these down to loading an image from a .jar file and removed the call from the code.  It worked for a while but is now crashing for images loaded from IFS.  Maybe RPGLE is locking the files somehow, and ideas?  The code is called from a Service Program.

Here is the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gnu.jpdf.PDFImage.write(PDFImage.java:286)
    at gnu.jpdf.PDFOutput.write(PDFOutput.java:114)
    at gnu.jpdf.PDFDocument.write(PDFDocument.java:307)
    at gnu.jpdf.PDFJob.end(PDFJob.java:182)
    at com.mysite.pdf.PdfDocumentStateValid.endDocument(PdfDocumentStateValid.java:657)
    at com.mysite.pdf.PdfDocument.endDocument(PdfDocument.java:36)
java.io.IOException: Descriptor not valid.
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:196)
    at java.lang.Exception.<init>(Exception.java:41)
    at java.io.IOException.<init>(IOException.java:40)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:112)
    at gnu.jpdf.PDFOutput.<init>(PDFOutput.java:96)
    at gnu.jpdf.PDFDocument.write(PDFDocument.java:302)
    at gnu.jpdf.PDFJob.end(PDFJob.java:182)
    at java.awt.PrintJob.finalize(PrintJob.java:60)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:116)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:47)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:193)
```

Comment: How is it crashing?  Can you post a stack trace or error message?

Comment: Also, which version of the OS are you on? And which version of RPG are you using (I think LE uses IV????) Sorry if I butcher this. I come from a split RPG/Java shop but I work explicitly with Java.

Comment: We are on iSeries V6R1M0 and running Java 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Changing my answer here now that I can see the stack trace. The problem happens when you hit native code (native meaning you are basically drilling into OS level or OS custom code).

You are getting an IOException of Descriptor not valid (and by that I'm assuming it means the file descriptor (ie, FileDescriptor). Now the big difference between running it in QShell and running it from RPG is that the Java code invoked from RPG is probably invoked under a different ID and/or privilege level. You may have to make modifications to the iSeries to your program to grant it authority for Java to have the right authorities to do what it needs. (I know you would think that is something the SecurityManager in Java would have picked up...but I know wierd things can happens sometimes when you are using a custom JVM (read IBM's) on a custom OS (i5/OS). You are left to the mercy of the vendor (in this case IBM). Give that a shot (the permissions thing) and see if that solves your problem.

Also...I googled and just found this related to iSeries: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas379538999e744aad1862575b0006e28ab
So it might be that the jt400 library used by the OS may have a flaw and you may need to PTF it and/or your JVM too. Just another thought of something to try.

Comment: Hi, all class files are definitely loaded and all rpgle prototypes are correct.

Comment: I remember us having to download some Unix "pack" thing so we could access some image libraries that weren't available to the iSeries by default. Kinda fuzzy on it. But I remember doing it before. That ring a bell with any of your searches?

Comment: Not sure about that.  I have actually had the images drawn to the PDF in certain circumstances which are difficult to reproduce, so I assume all is well with the libraries.  It is using simple java.awt and I am in headless mode.

Comment: I did check that PTF form IBM and was sure that that was the problem but I discovered that it is already installed on the system.  If Java was under a different security level, why would it work sometimes and not others?

Comment: No so much Java as the RPG program. If the RPG program runs under a different authority level than your program does outside of RPG, then it is possible that might be where the problem is?? At least it is something to verify/rule out.